# How to create Ext.Net Charts in Server Side

Tags: javascript, extjs, charts, server-side, ext.net

I need to create a chart in server side. It has to be this way because it will be a dynamic number of charts. I did not find anything that could help me.

In short, I need to implement this example in server side :

http://examples2.ext.net/#/Chart/Line/Basic/

Something like this:

```
public class GraficoMovimentacaoDiaria : Chart
    {
        public GraficoMovimentacaoDiaria(int[] dias, int ultimodia, string StoreId)
        {
            this.StyleSpec = "background:#fff;";
            this.Shadow = true;
            this.Animate = true;
            this.StandardTheme = StandardChartTheme.Category1;
            this.LegendConfig = new ChartLegend { Position = LegendPosition.Right };
            this.Store = ?????


        }
    }
```

Comment: Related [Ext.NET forum thread](http://forums.ext.net/showthread.php?60280).

Answer (score 1):

Please use:

```
this.Store.Add(new Store());
```

Related [Ext.NET forum thread](http://forums.ext.net/showthread.php?60280).